# GWT I18N javascript issue for property 'locale'

Tags: javascript, gwt, localization, internationalization, locale

I am having the following error when loading my GWT project (while trying to get the locale working...):

```
Error while executing the JavaScript provider for property 'locale'
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) __gwt_getProperty([string: 'locale']): undefined is not a function
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:249)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:576)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:284)
```

I followed these instructions:

First in the module file:

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N"/>

<extend-property name="locale" values="en" />
<extend-property name="locale" values="zh" />
<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en" />
<set-configuration-property name="locale.useragent" value="Y" />
```

Also created a basic Constants class as follow:

```
import com.google.gwt.i18n.client.Constants;

public interface LocaleConstants extends Constants {

    @Key("locale.name")
    String localeName();

    @Key("locale.code")
    String localeCode();

    @DefaultStringValue("Hello")
    String hello();

[...]
```

with corresponding properties files like 'LocaleConstants_en.properties':

```
locale.name=English
locale.code=en
hello=Hi
```

I tried a new project from scratch and it works well. I can't figure out what is causing issue in my existing project.

Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you create your own locale names and codes?

Comment: I am using them for display to allow user to change the locale. There is surely a better way to do that but it should not be related to my issue since the same code works well in a brand new project right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the locale in your host page (in the `<head>`):

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=en">
```

Comment: I actually did this as well but it didn't seem to change anything... until I eventually found the reason: My browser was caching the old version of my host html page (without this meta tag)... hence the error. Anyway your answer is definitively correct since from a GWT perspective, that was the issue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem as you did.

Alternatively, you can write the meta tag as

`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

to bypass this issue.

However, the current HTML5 meta tag format 
`<meta charset="UTF-8">` would cause another error as 
`com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) __gwt_getProperty([string: 'locale']): j[a] is not a function` so please don't use the HTML5 supported shortened meta for charset.